# Spacing on the top of a div because of different height of the page

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I have the "latest news" section under the first wrapper on top positioned `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` and `bottom: 0;`

Under that is a background-color and a DIV for the latest news. When the height of the browser/screen is changed there is some spacing at the top that randomly appears, I don't know why. Someone help?

Here is the JSBIN

http://jsbin.com/doqatene/1/edit?html,output

Basically I want to make sure that the DIV: latest news stays right under the wrapper and people can still scroll down the page.

For some reason in the JS bin you can't even see the wrapper so here is the scratchpad:

http://scratchpad.io/pumped-smash-2983

Comment: Basically I want to make sure that the DIV: latest news stays right under the wrapper and people can still scroll down the page.

Comment: I figued out that the wrapper should not be set to bottom: 0; but should be set to a certain height. in this case i set height: 42em; and now the content below does not move at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background: #333 url('https://archive.nyafuu.org/foolfuuka/boards/wg/image/1382/01/1382018045865.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.wrapper {
color: #fff;
}
.content {
height: 33.2em;
}
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/doqatene/3/)

Comment: I added that but the content div has to be positioned below the wrapper, I get the same problem. the .content div still moves.

Comment: Look http://jsbin.com/doqatene/3/ - you can play with styles. I removed `position: absolute`.

Comment: I figued out that the wrapper should not be set to bottom: 0; but should be set to a certain height. in this case i set height: 42em; and now the content below does not move at all.

Comment: hat does not fix the problem though user3388636, you got rid of the background color and now everything is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.content` `position: relative;` instead of absolute.

Now your `.news` html will be absolute based on the position of `.content`. You had absolute for both. This should be simplest solution. You'll need to readjust your position values like `top:42em;` to something lower now probably.

Also, for your `top:` you're using em. I would recommend using a `%` instead. The ems is causing the text to move around not evenly with the background image, when you change the window height. Then also remove the `height:` property off of `.content`. So to summarize, could look like this:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 85%;
}
```